# Rails, Angular, REST API with nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, rest

I'm using Rails as a proxy between a REST server and an AngularJS frontend.
The rest resources (POST/GET) are stored as class objects (no ActiveRecord because no local db).
I have an issue with nested attributes example  `{profile: [{"nested_1": "a descr"} , {"nested_2": "other desc"}]}`

How do i tell the Rails controller to allow nested attributes for the object sent by Angular ?

I an Unpermitted Parameters error when the controller processes updates/creates actions

P.S. I'm not fluent in Rails and all answers to the unpermitted params / with nested attributes error relates to ActiveRecord which i don't rely on.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your profile params should be slightly rewritten to match strong parameters policy:

```
params = {profile: {"nested_1" => "a descr", "nested_2" => "other desc"} }
parameters = ActionController::Parameters.new(params)
parameters.require(:profile).permit(:nested_1, :nested_2)
#  => {"nested_1"=>"a descr", "nested_2"=>"other desc"}
```

As can be seen [here](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters/blob/master/lib/action_controller/parameters.rb#LC30), `Parameters` class extends `HashWithIndifferentAccess` so that profile params must not be an `Array`, but a `Hash`.

Comment: An array can be used inside ```Parameters```. https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#nested-parameters

Comment: I agree for nested attributes, e.g `"nested_2" => []`, however having such: `profile: ["nested_1" => "a descr", "nested_2" => "other desc"]` and then `params.require(:profile).permit(...)` will end with exception.

Comment: ```parameters.permit(profile: [])``` works fine here.